# How can I free esriControls.ControlsSelectTool? Or is it leaking memory?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

In my application I have isues with unfreed memory. After several tries I broke down the problem to a simplified WPF project. It opens a simple System.Windows.Window with a Button, which starts the `MapWindow` listed below. The MapWindow has only an `AxMapControl` which loads a sample map, an `AxTocControl` and an `AxToolbarControl` both buddys of the MapControl.

I simply test the memory usage by looking at the task manager. When I hit the start button the first time the `MapWindow` opens and the memory usage is (depending on the project file and the size of `MapControl`) let's say 100 MB. Close the MapWindow and the memory goes down to ca. 65 MB. Hit the start button again (~100 MB) and close the window (~65 MB). This works fine for every iteration.

Now uncomment the line

```
toolbarControl.AddItem("esriControls.ControlsSelectTool");
```

and repeat the test. Hit the start button (~105 MB), close (~70 MB) and start (~115 MB), close (~80 MB), start (~125 MB) and close (~90 MB) and so on.

As you can see, the memory usage adds ~10 MB per start/close. The actual amount depends on the project and (!) on the size of the MapControl (even if no layer is activated in TOC on start up). So I asume, that there is some kind of bitmap cached and not freed correctly.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior? Is there a way to manually free this `ControlsSelectTool`? Or is this a bug that needs to be reported to Esri?

Here comes the code for the MapWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ArcEngineTest
{
  public partial class MapWindow : Window
  {
    AxMapControl _mapControl;
    AxToolbarControl _toolbarControl;
    AxTOCControl _tocControl;

    public MapWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      _mapControl = new AxMapControl();
      mapHost.Child = _mapControl;

      _toolbarControl = new AxToolbarControl();
      toolbarHost.Child = _toolbarControl;

      _tocControl = new AxTOCControl();
      tocHost.Child = _tocControl;

      Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(LoadMap);    
    }

    private void LoadMap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      _tocControl.SetBuddyControl(_mapControl);
      _toolbarControl.SetBuddyControl(_mapControl);

      //_toolbarControl.AddItem("esriControls.ControlsSelectTool"); // uncomment this line to cause memory leak; only happens with this specific esriControl ControlsSelectTool

      _mapControl.LoadMxFile(@"Z:\project.mxd");
      _mapControl.Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        // Free memory

        mapHost.Child = null;
        toolbarHost.Child = null;
        tocHost.Child = null;

        _tocControl.SetBuddyControl(null);
        _tocControl.Dispose();
        _tocControl = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < _toolbarControl.Count; i++)
        {
          ReleaseComObject(_toolbarControl.GetItem(i));
        }
        _toolbarControl.SetBuddyControl(null); // necessary
        _toolbarControl.RemoveAll();
        _toolbarControl.Dispose();
        _toolbarControl = null;

        _mapControl.Dispose();
        _mapControl = null;

        toolbarHost.Dispose();
        mapHost.Dispose();
        tocHost.Dispose();

        ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.COMSupport.AOUninitialize.Shutdown();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, "Error on Close");
      }
      base.OnClosed(e);
    }

    public static void ReleaseComObject(object obj)
    {
      if (obj != null)
      {
        int refsLeft = 0;
        do
        {
          refsLeft = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
        while (refsLeft > 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The correspondening xaml file is pretty simple:

```
<Window x:Class="ArcEngineTest.MapWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowState="Maximized">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="toolbarHost" Height="30"/>

    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" Name="tocHost" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Columns" />
    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="mapHost" />

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**

I could provide the test project (Visual Studio 2010 SP1). If anyone is interested, please comment.